# how set failOnError=“false” in Liquibase maven?

Tags: maven, liquibase

how can i set failOnError=“false” for all changeSet when generate changeLog with maven Liquibase:Diff

```
<changeSet author="aliakbarazizkhani (generated)" id="1468579261546-1" failOnError="false">
    <addColumn tableName="core_feedback">
        <column name="solveuser" type="bytea"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an option you can set on the command line. You would need to manually edit the changelog after it was generated to add the failOnError attribute to the appropriate change sets. It would be inadvisiable to apply that to all generated change sets.

Comment: manually? i want to use liquibase in continues delivery for remove humans and manually process .not make new human process.

Comment: how can it  do that automatically?

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the problem you are trying to solve. Why do you want to circumvent this feature? In general, you do not want to continue deploying changes if one of them fails.

If you really do want to apply this attribute to all the generated change sets, I would recommend writing a small program using a scripting language that can read/write XML, or use an XSLT transform.

Comment: can i do it with preConditions ?

Comment: Can you do what with preConditions? 

Again, what problem are you trying to solve? You seem to be focused on a solution rather than on a problem.

Comment: i want to continue when fail execute sql for all change set

Comment: Again, you are talking about the solution, not the problem. Why would you want to continue after failure? That is a Very Bad Idea. Doing that you are virtually guaranteed to end up with a database in a bad state.